# How to disable Android Studio spellcheck for certain C++ line, string, or scope?

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio you can suppress spellchecking warnings in Java and Kotlin files for specific items or scopes using a `@SuppressWarnings` annotation. Does something similar exist for C++ files?

For example, I have some JNI calls like:

```cpp
env->GetMethodID(cls, "getSomeObject", "()Ljava/lang/Object;")
```

Android Studio's spellchecker flags `Ljava` as a typo. It would be a typo if it occurred anywhere else, but as this string should have a specific format, it shouldn't be spellchecked.

Is there an annotation or magic comment to do this for C++ source, that Android Studio recognizes?

I know how to add "ljava" to the spelling dictionary, but ideally there would be another way to do this; I'd still want "ljava" to be flagged as a typo if I typed it in prose.